# Rails + Stripe: How to send out form (and handle errors) with AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, stripe-payments

I am battling recent days with Stripe. My problem is that I am trying to create a subscription with using AJAX (where I am failing right now) and also to validate entered credit card information.

Here's my workflow:

**JS CODE FOR HANDLING THE FORM:**

```
$('.show_subscriptions').hide();
$("#display_checkout_box").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'new_just_form') %>");

var subscription;
jQuery(function() {         
    // VALIDATIONS
    $('#card_number').payment('formatCardNumber');
    $('#card_expiration').payment('formatCardExpiry');
    $('#card_code').payment('formatCardCVC');

    $.fn.toggleInputError = function(erred) {
      this.parent('.form-group').toggleClass('has-error', erred);
      return this;
    };
    // end VALIATIONS

    Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'));
    return subscription.setupForm();
});
subscription = {
    setupForm: function() {     
      $('#new_subscription').submit(function() {            
            subscription.processCard();
            return false;
    });
  },
  processCard: function() {
        $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true).val('Processing. Please, wait...');
        $('input[type=submit]').addClass('processing');

        // STRIPE JS VALIDATION
        var cardType = $.payment.cardType($('#card_number').val());
        $('#card_number').toggleInputError(!$.payment.validateCardNumber($('#card_number').val()));
        $('#card_expiration').toggleInputError(!$.payment.validateCardExpiry($('#card_expiration').payment('cardExpiryVal')));
        $('#card_code').toggleInputError(!$.payment.validateCardCVC($('#card_code').val(), cardType));
        // end STRIPE JS VALIDATION

    var card;
    var exp_date = $('#card_expiration').val().split("/");

    card = {
      number: $('#card_number').val(),
      cvc: $('#card_code').val(),
      expMonth: parseInt(exp_date[0]),
      expYear: parseInt(exp_date[1])
    };
    return Stripe.createToken(card, subscription.handleStripeResponse);
  },
  handleStripeResponse: function(status, response) {
    if (status === 200) {
      $('#subscription_stripe_card_token').val(response.id);
      return $('#new_subscription')[0].submit();
    } else {
      console.log("Stripe Error: "+response.error.message);
      $('#subscribe_button').removeClass('processing');
      return $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false).val('Subscribe');
    }
  }
};
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
  def create
    @subscription = Subscription.new(subscription_params)
    if @subscription.save_with_payment(params[:coupon_id])
      redirect_to my_subscriptions_path, :notice => "You've successfully create a subscription for your team member!"
    else
      redirect_to '/account', :alert => "There is a problem with your credit card, we are unable to make the charge."
    end
  end
```

**MODEL:**

```
def save_with_payment(coupon_id)
    if valid?
      plan = Plan.find(plan_id)    
      Stripe.api_key = STRIPE_CONFIG['secret_key']

       description = "#{plan.name} subscription for #{email}"

      # create a subscription on Stripe
      unless coupon_id.empty?
        customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: description,
                                           email: email, 
                                           plan: plan.plan_code, 
                                           card: stripe_card_token, 
                                           trial_end: 'now', 
                                           coupon: coupon_id)
        coupon_data = Coupon.where('coupon_name = ?', coupon_id).first
      else
        customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: description, 
                                           email: email, 
                                           plan: plan.plan_code, 
                                           card: stripe_card_token, 
                                           trial_end: 'now')      
      end
      self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
      # retrieve information about the current subscription
      cstmr = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(customer.id)
      subscr = cstmr.subscriptions.first
      self.start = Time.at(subscr.start)
      self.status = subscr.status
      self.subscription_code = subscr.id
      unless coupon_id.empty? # there was applied a coupon code on this subscription
        self.coupon_id = coupon_data.id        
      end
      # end of: retrieve information about the current subscription


      # fetch user.id
      user_id = User.where('email = ?', email).first
      self.user_id = user_id.id
      # end of: fetch user.id
      save!
    end

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    logger.error "Stripe error while creating customer (That card is presently on fire!): #{e.message}"
    errors.add :base, "That card is presently on fire!"
    false
  rescue => e
    logger.error "Stripe error while creating customer: #{e.message}"
    errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card."
    false
  end
```

If I enter all credit card information correct, the form is sent out (in the regular way) and the respective subscription is created. How to send this form with using AJAX, so after sending the form wouldn't be the page redirected?

I am also trying to display (possible) errors in the form (or generally said - on the same page). Right now, when a user fills incorrect the CVC code, then the error message (the `rescue` part) is displayed once the page is redirected?
How to display it inside the form?

I would be very grateful for every advice, my hair is turning grey from it already.

Thank you in advance, guys.

**EDIT:**
For jQuery validation, I use the [Stripe jQuery](https://github.com/stripe/jquery.payment) library.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use JQuery to AJAX Post the form and stripe token to the controller. Make sure to prevent the default form submission first. If you have a lot of response data from the server, it would be good to use JSON for return.

```
var form_data = {
  name: name,
  email: email,
  plan_id: plan_id,
  stripe_token: stripeToken,
} 

$.post( "#{subscriptions_path}",  form_data, function(server_data) {
   result = jQuery.parseJSON(server_data);
   if (result.status == 'success') {
     // redirect to their dashboard or wherever you want to take them
     window.location = '/dashboard';
   }else {
     //print the errors in the page.
     $('#error_message').show().text(result.error_msg)
   }

)};

def create
  @subscription = Subscription.new(subscription_params)
  if @subscription.save_with_payment(params[:coupon_id])
    render json: {status: 'success', subscription: @subscription}
  else
    render json: {status: 'failed', subscription: @subscription, error_msg: @subscription.errors.full_messages.to_sentence }
 end
end
```